# Way to prevent speaking fluency of acquired language to be lost or possibly enhance it further

Tags: learning-methods, speaking, language-exchange

In general fluency, there was a related question: [How can I prevent myself from forgetting a language?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-can-i-prevent-myself-from-forgetting-a-language) which suggest speaking to yourself a lot. But how about your general speaking fluency? I have a case where I could read, listen to the native language (English in this case) speaker/writer very well. But when I respond, I could do well in writing, but unable to speak that fluent to reply.

Some possible way I could think of was:

1. Join a group where there is some native speaker or acquire some native speaker friends to be your partner to converse daily.
2. Keep learning the language so your vocabulary knowledge would be enhanced further so you don't have any problem to construct sentences.

Is there any way to prevent your speaking fluency to be lost or possibly enhance it further other than mentioned? Or possibly my way is a mistaken guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch videos and movies from two sources:

- reliable sources such as the BBC news website or PBS (US) that have programs or news on interesting topics in decent English.
- watch movies in English, trying to separate out slang from non-slang.

And turn on the **close captioning to make sure you are "getting it all".**

As you listen, repeat what you hear. Take notes on expressions you do not. Pay special attention to minor things that can affect fluency such as: at a place versus in or inside a place.

Try to concentrate on details like that and ones like: the verb mind is following by a gerund: Do you mind opening the window?

You will know what to take note of and write down.

Anyway,those are two ways of keeping verbal fluency.

Comment: I agree with a lot of this but I think there is a huge difference between constructing your own sentences and parroting what you have heard, so I suggest stopping the video and trying to come up with a response of your own. If there's a video you can stand to watch many times, trying to remember the next bit of dialogue is quite good because you can never remember it perfectly, so you have to fill in the gaps yourself. Actually speaking to a native is much better though, if you can arrange that.

Comment: The question was about keeping up one's fluency. This method is used by interpreters. You only try and write down or re-use things you have forgotten. Not entire sentences.